# Display grid items onClick function not working react

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I have made a grid that displays 4 grid items and onlick of the button I want it to display all grids items.

I have successfully set the items to not display but my function for them to display when the button is clicked is not working.
please see my code below.

```
const Brands = () => {

  const divContainer = document.querySelectorAll("hidden");
  let showOrHide = function(){
    divContainer.style.display = "inline-block";
  }


  return (
 <>
 
 <div className={styles.brandcont}>
  <h2>Client Portfolio</h2>
 <div className={styles.cont}>
    <div className={styles.gucci}> <img alt="gucci logo" src={gucci}/></div>
    <div className={styles.fendi}> <img alt="fendi logo" src={fendi}/></div>
    <div className={styles.amq}> <img alt="alexander mcqueen logo" src={amq}/></div>
    <div className={styles.zegna}> <img alt="Zegna logo" src={zegna}/></div>
    <div className={styles.givenchy}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={givenchy}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={alfies}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={arije}/></div>
   
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={bottega}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={breitling}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={brunello}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={louboutin}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={churchs}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={dolce}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={eden}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={grays}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={boss}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={kenzo}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={lacoste}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={loewe}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={longchamp}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={missoni}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={moschino}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={mulberry}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={prada}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={rimowa}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={ferragamo}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={stella}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={tg}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={time}/></div>

    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={ford}/></div>
    <div className={styles.gucci} id={styles.hidden}> <img alt="Givenchy logo" src={valentino}/></div>
  
 </div>

 <button onClick={showOrHide} className={styles.portbutton}>Full Portfolio</button>
 </div>

 </>
  )
}

export default Brands
```

is there a simple way to correct this ?

I have removed the imports as it wouldnt let me post the question with too much code